# TimeSpan how to save and update

Tags: c#

OK .. here is one that I find interesting. I am using a datatable to hold a bunch of values. I need to store a TimeSpan. I am able to make a column for the TimeSpan data type. I am able to insert the data into the column. Now comes the interesting part ...

I need to pull out that TimeSpan data and add another TimeSpan data value to it and resave it. I see that there is no way to '.toTimeSpan' it from a string. Which is the way i am trying to bring it back from the table.

So ... Anyone out there have the answer here?

The code is in C#

Answer (score 2):

If you've already *got* it in the `DataTable`, can't you just cast the value?

```
TimeSpan span = (TimeSpan) row["foo"];
TimeSpan total = span + otherSpan;
row["foo"] = total;
```

I'd expect the trickier bit to be storing it in a database - and if you're *not* storing it in a database, I wouldn't use `DataTable` in the first place, I'd just a collection.

Comment: I have to retrieve it out of the table and store it. Then the datatable gets cleared and all the new row is written with the updated values.

Comment: @user1588668: Store it where? It's not really clear what you're asking here. Are you really sure you need to use a `DataTable` here at all?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're just storing them as a string, this should work;

```
string dbSpanString = "03:50:03"; // From DB
TimeSpan span = TimeSpan.Parse(spanString);
```

If storing as a time datatype, you can just use SqlDataReader.GetTimeSpan() as well.

TimeSpan has its operators overloaded so you can either use +/- or TimeSpan.Add.